# Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

Tags: r

I have a column of dates with some dates missing and having NA instead.
Dates are in format of Date and expressed as: 2010-09-02

[image: If picture helps]

I am trying to convert if the cell has date in it to convert it to 1, and if NA to 0.

So far I have:

`LoanData$DefaultDate[!is.na(as.Date(LoanData$DefaultDate, origin = "1970-01-01")) == TRUE] <- 1`

and I keep receiving an error:

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

Googled the error, but still did not find any explanation.
Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Please include actual sample data.

Comment: For next time: ```dput(LoanData$DefaultDate)```, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as.Date will return `NA` if it finds an NA or the format is wrong. Therefore you can just check whether it is an NA after transformation with `is.na`. This returns a logical, which can be inverted with `!` and transformed into integer with `*1`

```
v <- c("2010-09-02", NA, "2010-06-02")

(!is.na(as.Date(v)))*1
[1] 1 0 1
```

Most likely in your data:

```
LoanData$DefaultDate <- (!is.na(as.Date(LoanData$DefaultDate)))*1
```